# Connect Apple Cinema Display to Ubuntu Laptop

Tags: 18.04, multiple-monitors

Hi I just bought a dell precision mobile 5540 (developer edition) running Ubuntu Linux 18.04.3 LTS with all the latest updates applied.

I have 2 apple cinema displays (circa 2011) and an adapter to convert them the Mini DP to Thunderbolt.  The setup (connecting the monitors using adapter) worked for windows 10 and mac of course with no issues but my Ubuntu laptop does not recognize the displays with a similar setup.

Anyone had this experience and able to shed some light?

Comment: Disconnect the adapter. In a command line window, type `journalctl --follow`. Connect the adapter. Look at the log messages in the command line window. Type `^C` when done

Comment: Nice tip.  That helped.  I managed to see the log trace that Thunderbolt had exceeded limit.  I went to BIOS settings (F2 after restart) and changed the Thunderbolt to be Native BIOS and the external apple monitors are working again.

Comment: When I run that command I get this:
pcieport 0000:00:1d.0: PME: Spurious native interrupt!
ucsi_acpi USBC000:00: UCSI_GET_PDOS failed (-95)
ucsi_acpi USBC000:00: UCSI_GET_PDOS failed (-95)

Anyone have any ideas how I can debug this?